# android studio iguana 2023.2.1 en notificaciones me sale *daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, google-developers-console

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBu7C.png)
android studio iguana 2023.2.1 en notificaciones me sale
*daemon started successfully
*daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

no se como solucionarlo porque soy nuevo en esto de programar por favor si alguien me puede ayudar se le agradecera

Comment: Que sistema operativo usas? que versión de android studio usas?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira que no tengas más de un android studio abierto a la vez

Comment: SO Windows 11 Pro versión 22H2 versión del sistema operativo 22321.2361 procesador Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU 2.6GHz, RAM 16GB, tarjeta de Video Nvidea GeForce 970m
Versión de Android: 2023.2.1 Canary 6 
también tengo el otro estable con la versión: 2022.3.1 Patch 2 Giraffe
ambos tiene el mismo problema

Comment: Solo ejecuto un Android a la vez, pero igual sea la versión que use siempre tiene ese error aun después de reinstalarlo

Answer (score 1):

Una solución para que funcione tu android studio es simplemente abrir el administrador de tareas usando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, ubicar el proceso `adb.exe` y abrir el menú contextual para finalizar este proceso (End task), el proceso volverá a iniciar automáticamente al iniciar android studio y debería funcionar.

[image: Android Studio end task]